# Sort by name in alphabetical order not working in data table

Tags: datatable, datatables, cakephp-3.2

Here i have fetched the data from controller , all are coming fine (according to the alphabetical order) ,but in data table its not coming what i want to get ,means in alphabetical order while viewing .

Here all the data in descending order by default

```html
aaSorting: [[0, "desc"]],
```

I need it to be sort according to the name field in alphabetical order

I have attached a snap for more clarification.
Here i want all the center name should be in alphabetical order.

[image]

Please suggest me.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: hi i have added a snap ,please  check @AneeshSivaraman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example1').DataTable({
           aaSorting: [[0, "asc"]]
        });
    });
</script>
```

After doing a research ,finally got to know this .
i just added this js codes below of this page .
And results came ,what i need.
It may be helpful to anyone else .

Thank you .