# datatables.net Unable to sort footer selection month name wise

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, datatable

Sorry I am new here and don't know how to ask queries.

I have a salary table. there is a column by which users can see the data of employees in month wise. I have used the example in https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html. But in the footer portion, it is showing the month name in alphabetical order, but I want it in January, February..... December.
I have uploaded the test cases here. Please check

http://live.datatables.net/rowufiru/1/

[the output image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiuSO.png)
My HTML code is

```
<table id="example1" class="display table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th data-field="start_date" data-sortable="true" data-footer-formatter="amountFormatter">Month</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Total salary</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="employee_data">
    <tr>
      <td>Akash</td>
      <td>December</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sumit</td>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Akash</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sumit</td>
      <td>April</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sumit</td>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Akash</td>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sumit</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Akash</td>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
                    }
                  ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Total salary</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried to sort the data ? can you share your js as well?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265301/sort-by-name-in-alphabetical-order-not-working-in-data-table

Comment: My js is as follows:

Comment: My js file is 

 $(function () {
$('#example1').DataTable( {
initComplete: function () {
this.api().columns([0, 1, 2, 3]).every( function () {
var column = this;
var select = $('<select><option value="">Show all</option></select>')
.appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
.on( 'change', function () {
var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
$(this).val()
);
column
.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
.draw();
} );
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
} );
} )
}
} );
})